# ActivityIndicator not showing when triggered before CoreML VNCoreMLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, uiactivityindicatorview, coreml

I'm using a swift ActivityIndicator : https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView

```
func runMLModel(image: CIImage, completion: @escaping ([MLMultiArray]) -> Void){
     let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: myModel) { (request, error) in
            guard let results = request.results as? [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation] else {
                fatalError("Model failed to process image")
            }
            //Do work here get mlData var
            completion(mlData)
        }

        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: image)

        do {
            try handler.perform([request])
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
}

func buttonPressedToDoMLWork(){

     self.startAnimating(CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), message: "loading", type: NVActivityIndicatorType.audioEqualizer)  
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()) {
        NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.setMessage("Authenticating...")

    }
    // Activity Indicator should be showing up here
    // but nothing is displayed
    runMLModel(image: myImage, completion: { (mlData : [MLMultiArray]) in

            print("got data")

            //indicator only shows up NOW.. after printing
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
                self.stopAnimating(nil)

            }        
        })
    }
}
```

It seems the code inside the CoreML module overrides the importance of launching the NVAcitivityIndicatorPresenter on the main DispatchQueue.

Anyway to make this darn indicator show up before the MLRequest is fired off?

Answer (score 0):

Put your rumMlmodel in delay function, don’t add activity code in async task. It will show your activity after that. Delay should be around 0.4 - 0.6